# Razor form is not showing all inputs (@Html.EditorFor) even after copy/pasting code

Tags: forms, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor, input

Every input is showing and working with the exception of Last Name and City. I've copy/pasted from two separate inputs in an attempt to get them all to work. I can't find a difference in the code anywhere but when I debut and inspect it, there is a label and verification but not input for both. I'm at a loss as to what is causing the inputs to be deleted for only these two elements.
[image: code output]
[image: inspect code]

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <!-- Customer Information -->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_First_Name, "First Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_First_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_First_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_Last_Name, "Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_Last_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_Last_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_Last_Name, "Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_Last_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_Last_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_Address, "Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_City, "City", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_City, "City", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_State, "State", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_Country, "Country", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Order Information -->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Total, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Total, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product_ID, "Product_ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownList("Product_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-right">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
                            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default ml-5" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was looking in the wrong place. The problem was not in my razor code but in the database. The data types for City and State were mistyped and this was causing them to not show in the debug. I corrected this in MS Sequel Studio by changing the fields in the database diagram. I used the database first Entity Framework setup and changing column specifications in the database threw Visual Studio for a loop so I tried dropping the Orders table I had changed and re-adding it to the .edmx but it's connected to the Products table which then started producing errors. In the end I had to delete the entire .edmx in Visual Studio then right click and refresh from database to add back the tables I needed to get the code to run correctly. My apologies for my incoherent question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,I test your code,it can work.If your EditFor not work,you can try to use input and span:

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_Last_Name, "Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="C_Last_Name" name="C_Last_Name" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="C_Last_Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>  
                </div>
            </div>
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_City, "City", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="C_City" name="C_City" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="C_City" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

result:

[image]